# Can I Construct Anything (Within Reason) When Building a Proof?

Tags: geometry

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I'm curious about this. Is it acceptable to claim anything (as long as it's logically sound) during construction when building a geometric proof? For example, let's say I have $\triangle$ ABC and $\triangle$ DEF. Let's say I had some givens and wanted to prove equivalence for these two triangles. What if I wanted to say there's some point G that when connected to B makes an angle congruent to the angle created by some point H connected to E? Is it logically acceptable to just state that the lines I created produced two angles that are equivalent to each other? Or do I have to prove that these angles are equivalent? I guess  I'm just unclear about where the line is drawn (no pun intended) for building ancillary statements when constructing a proof. Again, apologies if this is a silly question.

EDIT 1: I'm trying to prove that $\triangle$ ABC $\cong$ $\triangle$ DEF with the following givens:

1. $\angle$ A $\cong$ $\angle$ D
2. Segment AC $\cong$ Segment DF

I had the idea of saying that there was some point G connected to point B, and some point H connected to point E, connected in such a way that their angles were identical. I then wanted to declare/construct a point X that is an altitude and median for $\triangle$ GAB and a point Y that is also an altitude and a median for $\triangle$ DEH. I then went on to say that because $\triangle$ GAB and $\triangle$ DEH were isoceles, segment AB $\cong$ segment DE. That along with Givens 1 and 2 would have been my SAS proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement that something exists is itself a mathematical statement. On a formal level, if in the middle of a proof you assert the statement that some object exists satisfying some properties, then like any other step of a proof you must justify that statement. Sometime your justification will be an axiom, sometimes it will be an earlier construction, or maybe another theorem which has already be proved to be true.

As for writing your own proofs, I would say that your first audience is yourself: Are you convinced that *you* know the correct justification?

After that, generally speaking nothing is accepted as "self-evident" in mathematics. However, one should always keep one's readers or listeners in mind. If your reader/listener is a teacher, you have to know what standards they expect: for instance, probably your teacher won't require you to cite the very simplest axioms every time they are used to justify something in a proof. If your reader/listener is a peer or classmate, you have to have a feel for what they understand: if you and they have a common pool of understanding about the simplest principles of proof, again probably you do not have to justify things which fall within that common pool.

But here's a few experiences you *will* have if you pursue mathematics far enough: You will think some step of a proof is obvious, but your listener won't, and will demand a justification, and so you better hope you're ready to satisfy them! Or, you will think some step is obvious, but later on down the line you yourself will begin to have deep suspicions about the course of your proof, you will trace those suspicions back to the "obvious" step, which all of a sudden will stop being obvious, and you will *really, really* want to know whether that step can be justified.

Comment: I'm learning how to establish proofs, and some problems require using construction to establish a claim. Am I free to construct anything as long as it's logically sound? If I have a triangle am I always allowed to just construct some line and say that it's an altitude just because I declare it to be so?

Comment: I'll repeat the key point of my answer: "like any other step of a proof, you must justify that statement".

Comment: As in justify why I'm introducing that statement, or why that line is an altitude, or both? I'm not nitpicking this way to be pedantic or obtuse, I'm just having a hard time understanding what the rules are. Proofs are starting to feel more manageable now that I think that I have some freedom to introduce additional statements into an argument, but I can't tell if that's actually because I'm understanding the material or actually just not understanding the fundamentals of construction/building an argument.

Comment: In mathematics, to justify a statement means to give a proof of that statement. So, you may introduce additional statements, but only if you can prove that they are true, i.e. only if you can justify them. This is what keeps us from introducing additional statements which are *false*.

Comment: I hear you. Is it valid to say that a line segment I introduced is an altitude because it's perpendicular to a side within the triangle I put it in and that some point X is a point on that side? In this case it can be true, but only because I'm saying it to be so. So I don't think I'm doing something wrong per se, I just don't know if introducing something like this is allowed.

Comment: No, something is not true just because you say it is true. On the other hand, there are theorems of Euclidean geometry which prove the existence of an altitude. One of them goes like this: if all angles of a triangle are acute then there is an altitude from each vertex of that triangle to some point on the opposite side. You can try to prove that theorem if you like, or look up a proof in a geometry book. Once you know that theorem, you can use it in a justification: first verify that your triangle has acute angles, then you may conclude the altitude you want does indeed exist.

Comment: This explains a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How much you need to write to justify any statement in a proof depends a lot on context. If you are writing for an audience, you have to know how much they can fill in the details.

If you are writing homework for a course, your instructor should tell you how much detail to include.

I tell my students to write enough to convince me that they have convinced themselves for good reasons - convincing me is not enough since I already know what's true. In an advanced course it's OK to skip explanations for steps that are essentially elementary and "obvious". In an introductory course I expect to see complete arguments. If a student writes too much I can point out what's unnecessary.

Comment: I guess the difficulty I'm having is knowing what has to be defended rather than what can be presented as self-evident. For example, I'm beginning to understand the burden of proof for arguments around congruence, but I always feel timid when building ancillary arguments to reach that objective. As in, I get that I have to explicitly state, say, which sides and angle make a SAS claim, but I get nervous when I use a construction in support of that claim. Is it logically acceptable if I just say that two lines create congruent angles for two separate triangles?

Comment: @tryingtodomath If you [edit] the question to show us the mathematical context in which you want to say "two lines create congruent angles" we might be able to say what kind of support that assertion needs. As posed, your question is too abstract.

Comment: edit made above to include what I'm going for. I think I now realize that I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @tryingtodomath I hope that "barking up the wrong tree" means "trying to prove something that isn't true". You should be able to pictures of noncongruent triangles that have one angle and one side equal. If you could prove what you claim then "SA" would be as good as "SAS".